# Did you use to go to a gym in town?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence "Did you use to go to a gym in town?" The Word program changed use to used. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you used to feel / How did you use to feel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24468/how-do-you-used-to-feel-how-did-you-use-to-feel)

Comment: It's better to avoid this construction if you can. We don't really perceive the *use* in  *used to*, and we would tend to read *did you use to go* as having the normal meaning of *use* (we would pronounce it with a z sound, whereas it has to be an s sound for the *used to* meaning). I expect that *did you used to* will eventually be accepted, but for the time being most people will say it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, "did you used to go" is incorrect. Compare:

Statement: I went to a gym.

Question: Did you go to a gym? (Not "did you went to a gym?")

Statement: I used to go to a gym.

Question: Did you use to go to a gym? (Not "did you used to go to a gym.")

Notice that in both questions, the auxiliary verb "do" is in the past tense ("did"), while the main verb ("go" in the first set of examples, "use" in the second) is in base form.